# Find newest file. Multiple Filetype restrictions

Tags: files, find, sort, timestamps

I want to write a command that gives me the **newest file** in a directory **recursively**. But that's not my only limitation. The files has to be an **mp3** **or a jpg** file. (**case insensitive** prefered)
I only need the creating date of that newest file. If possible I want it formatted like this:
30-12-2014 (so: **day-month-year**)

This is currently wath I've got:

```
find .  -name '*.mp3' -or -name '*.JPG'   -printf "%TD \n" | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

But it doesn't work well. I only get JPG's and the date isn't formatted.

Comment: Check this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099?highlight=%28oldest%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
find . \( -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.jpg" \) -printf '%TY%Tm%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

This should find the files that (case-insensitively) find files ending with mp3 or jpg, print out the modification time, then sort it in reverse order.

It seems to show both file-types when you run it effectively as two commands:

```
( find . -iname "*.mp3" -printf '%TY%Tm%Td %TT %p\n' ; find . -iname "*.jpg" -printf '%TY%Tm%Td %TT %p\n' ) | sort -r
```

Comment: I'm only getting the .jpg files with that command. No mp3's are shown. Switching over themp3 and jpg, gives me only mp3's

Comment: @Wilf you need  `\( -iname '*.mp3 -o -iname '*.jpg' \)`  otherwise it will match one or the other.

Comment: @val0x00ff - thanks - wondered why it was being weird... it there a actual reason why find does this? I have previously found it has had problems with paths as well...

Comment: @Wilf  scroll just a bit down on this site: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind  and you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
zmodload zsh/stat
zstat -F %F +mtime -- **/(#i)*.(mp3|jpg)(Om[1])
```

Note that it's based on *last modification* time, the *creation time* (whatever that means) is generally not readily available on Linux.

It doesn't consider hidden files. I you want them, add the `D` globbing qualifier above.

Comment: euhm I'm using debian (and I'm a linux noob). These commands don't work. Do I need to install something, because I'd rather not.

Comment: You just have to type `zsh` and try the solution. In most of the systems, the `zsh` shell comes by default.

Comment: Nothing happens on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2):

Also see the following:

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -printf '%AY-%Am-%Ad %P \n'
```

Comment: I'm getting no output :/. Didn't crash though.

Comment: @user2815780  You can play with `-mtime -1` by changing the modification time.  For example  `-mtime -10` wich will search for mp3 or jpg files which are created 10 days from now  and ofcourse you can set  `|head -n4` or whatever you want at the end

Comment: doesn't work, sorry. Still no output. Altought according to file creation date it should give some output :/

Comment: @user2815780 'Still no output' is not enough. Maybe you need to increase  `-mtime -100`  to search for latest 100 dasys

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but it didn't work. I even set it to 999. Checked the clock on my system and checked the date of the files. sdtill no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You specified -or, that needs to be -o, as other have corrected.  You also need parentheses I think (correction on my original post).  I'd recommend using `%T@` for the format specifier (seconds since 1970) which is cleaner to sort; then you can convert it using

```
date --date="@`find . \\( -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.jpg" \\) -printf '%T@\n' | sort -rn | head -n1`"
```

or whatever.  You can also put in whatever date format you want using `+`.