# cd fails when trying to enter maldetect version-agnostic directory

Tags: debian, regular-expression, cd-command, access-control, malware

I'm installing Maldet on Debian 9.3:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
tar -xzvf maldetect-current.tar.gz 
cd maldetect-*
bash ./install.sh
```

While doing `cd maldetect-*` I got:

> Bash: Too many arguments

I tried doing `cd "maldetect-*"` but this command is invalid.

Why can't I access the dir?...

Comment: You are trying to cd into multiple directories. Put the full path of the directory in instead of the wild card.

Comment: But the full path is changing dynamically by each release, I have a big need to enter only once without the full path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `cd maldetect-*`, all files and directories that match that pattern are expanded on the command line. You have at least the `.tar` file, and probably a directory that was found inside it. You can only be in one directory at a time, so `cd` to multiple directories makes no sense.

In `cd "maldetect-*"`, there's no expansion. The command itself is fine, but you probably don't have a directory with an asterisk in the name, so it won't find anything to `cd` to.

If you know you only ever have one directory that matches the pattern, you could use `cd maldetect-*/` with a trailing slash to ask the shell to only expand directory names.

If you can have multiple directories that match the pattern, you'll have to either find the newest one or look inside the archive to find the name of the directory there.

Finding the newest is discussed in [BashFAQ 003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) (or maybe [BashFAQ 099](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099)), and probably some questions on-site, like [Find newest file. Multiple Filetype restrictions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147454/find-newest-file-multiple-filetype-restrictions).

In the trivial case where all file names are known to be nice `ls -tr | tail -1` might work, but see 
[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Of course it shouldn't be too hard to peek inside the archive, but this also assumes the archive is 'nice' in a number of ways:

```
$ tar tzf maldetect-current.tar.gz | head -1 | cut -d/ -f1
maldetect-1.6.2
```

Comment: Thank you. Thumb up for the didactance. I think your answer was perfect even before the last edit.